# How to pass Hidden field values using GET method

Tags: java, html

I have GET Method. I want to pass something like Student_id in request but without showing it in URL. I know for that we use POST Method. But I dont want to use POST since I am getting someother issues.

Comment: don't worry you are not going to be able to hide it from the clever user, might aswell use post or get(visible in url)

Comment: You can encode it somehow but you can't stop it from appearing in your URL if you use GET. That is what POST is for, as you mentioned.

Comment: You can't hide it from appearing i URL, you have to use HTTP POST/PUT instead.

Answer (score 2):

If Student_id is something you don't want the user to have, then don't send it. Ever. There's no way to make it safe once it's in a user's hands.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use a frame as a mask so the domain doesn't change whilst the form submits. You can sneak a REFRESH header in there for 0 seconds with the _top addition, making it nearly impossible for someone to follow your form's weaknesses.

Answer (score 1):

You can't eat the cake and leave it whole.

Your best option is to encrypt the Student_id somehow, you can have your own simple method if it's not very sensitive data, and you can use more complicated algorithms but it can never be 100% safe.

Another option is to not submit the form at all, but AJAX instead to pass the values to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it.

First learn the difference between get and post method.

Get is used to query something with some parameter and post is used to create or update content in the server via http.

It is better using ajax get if you want to hide the parameters form the user.

Look at these link:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Cant help to wonder, what does this have anything to do with java.. However, to understand your problem. I would suggest that you use [$_SESSSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) or [setcookie();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) So before sending the user to another page, you would first save the user_id in some form.